# Regex in Word 2016

Tags: regex, ms-word, ms-office, wildcard

I am not very into coding right now. I got a Regex task solved in the Word Regex Search function.

Question to solve: What is the Regex to find all numbers between 1,000 and 9,999.

This is what I got so far: " **[1-9]{1}\,[0-9]{3}**". the expression **\b** does not work in Word so I used just a blank space in front of the expression.

Is there a way to get it working in Word? In Notepad++ the Expression.  **\b** is actually working?

Regards Johannes

Comment: Try `<[1-9],[0-9]{3}>`

Comment: Great, works thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In MS Word, `\b` regex word boundaries do not work, the construct you need is `<` and `>`:

```
<[1-9],[0-9]{3}>
```

The `<` is a leading word boundary and `>` is a trailing word boundary.

To avoid matching the value before another comma (so as not to match `1,000` inside `1,000,000`) you may use

```
<[1-9],[0-9]{3}>[!,]
```

where `[!,]` matches any chars but a comma. Note that `<[1-9],[0-9]{3}>[!,]` won't match a *1-9,999* number at the end of the document (it will if there is any other char after the number).

Comment: The only issue now: When I use <[1-9]{1}\.[0-9]{3}> to find numbers between 1.000 and 9.999 (not American writing) the expression also finds for example "1.000.000" is this a Word Bug or possible to solve this? –

Comment: @Johannesv.R. No, it is not a bug. Word boundaries match when the word chars are not preceded/followed with word chars and since `,` is not a word char, `1,000` matches in `1,000,000`. You might want to use something like `[!,]` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: What Is [!.] doing? Doesn't work when we use " <[1-9]{1}\.[0-9]{3}[!.]>"

Comment: @Johannesv.R. You are using `,` as digit grouping symbols. Use `[!,]`.

Comment: But in our WordDoc, they are using . as digit grouping... I need it for . thats causing problems.

Comment: @Johannesv.R. Then just replace a `,` with `.` (escaping it outside the character class), use `<[1-9]\.[0-9]{3}>[!.]`

Comment: @Johannesv.R. You must NOT use a space before `<`. Just use `<[1-9]\.[0-9]{3}>[!.]` and it works in my Word.